# Binary Tree creation in C

Tags: c, tree

I have created a program to generate a tree using a double-linked list and queues, which are also implemented with the help of a single-linked list. However, I am encountering a problem. When I input, for example, `7`, the program prompts for left and right only once, and then it terminates. Upon tracing the program, it should take all inputs properly instead of terminating after just two numbers. I have attempted to debug the program several times, and I am quite frustrated at this point. Could you please check for any issues in the enqueue, dequeue, or create functions, or perhaps in the global declarations? I appreciate your assistance. Thank you

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tree {
    struct tree *lchild;
    int data;
    struct tree *rchild;
} tree;//create

typedef struct Queue {
    tree *data;
    struct Queue *next;
} Queue;//isEmptyQ,isFullQ,enQueue,deQueue

Queue *f = NULL;
Queue *r = NULL;
tree *root;

int isEmptyQ()
{
    return r == NULL || f == NULL;
}

int isFullQ()
{
    Queue *t = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    return t == NULL;
}

void enQueue(tree *data)
{
    if (!isFullQ())
    {
        Queue *t = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
        t->data = data;
        t->next = NULL;  // Initialize next pointer to NULL

        if (r == NULL && f == NULL)
        {
            r = f = t;
        }
        else
        {
            r->next = t;
            r = t;
        }
    }
}

tree *deQueue()
{
    if (!isEmptyQ())
    {
        Queue *temp = f;
        tree *t = f->data;
        f = f->next;
        free(temp);
        return t;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void create()
{
    root = malloc(sizeof(tree));
    int data;
    printf("Enter the data to be entered:");
    scanf("%d", &data);
    root->data = data;
    root->lchild = root->rchild = NULL;
    enQueue(root);

    tree *p = NULL;
    while (!isEmptyQ())
    {
        p = deQueue();
        printf("Left? of %d (-1 for no left child):", p->data);
        scanf("%d", &data);
        if (data != -1)
        {
            tree *t = malloc(sizeof(tree));
            t->data = data;
            t->lchild = t->rchild = NULL;
            p->lchild = t;
            enQueue(t);
        }

        printf("Right? of %d (-1 for no right child):", p->data);
        scanf("%d", &data);
        if (data != -1)
        {
            tree *t = malloc(sizeof(tree));
            t->data = data;
            t->lchild = t->rchild = NULL;
            p->rchild = t;
            enQueue(t);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    create();
}
```

Comment: Now seems to be a very good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through your code line by line while monitoring variables and their values. Use pencil and paper at the same time to draw the lists and the trees you create.

Comment: Sir,i have tried the same and for some reason it works perfectly,but when i run it .I am no where'

Comment: As a general tip, don't write large pieces of code without testing. Start with an empty `main` function. Build with extra warnings enabled and treated as errors. Only when your code builds cleanly, then test it. Once it passes all tests, add a ***very small*** bit of code, perhaps even just one or two lines. Build and test as before. That will make it much easier to figure out and debug and solve problems when you get them. Perhaps even isolate the problematic code into a separate [mre].

Comment: Your `isFullQ` is flawed and leaks memory. I recommend you separate the queue from the nodes in the queue into their own structures. So you have one structure for the queue itself, with `front` and `rear` members as well as `size` and `max_size` members. And stop using global variables, use local variables and pass arguments to functions when needed. Do something similar to the tree. And please add some empty lines to break up the code into paragraphs, which makes it easier to read.

Comment: And depending on which compiler you're using, you can build with *sanitizers* which helps find bad things your code might be doing. With Clang or GCC add the options `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dequeue function seems to lack proper handling of the case where the queue gets empty.

As far as I can see the two global(!) variables `f` and `r` represent *front* and *rear* of a linked list.

When doing dequeue of the front element you will "normally" only need to update the value of `f`. However, there is a special case when the linked list only contains a single element. In that case, you need to update both `f` and `r`.

So after changing `f` check whether `r` needs to be updated. Perhaps like:

```
f = f->next;               // existing line
if (f == NULL) r = NULL;   // add this line
```

Further, you should reconsider the function `isFullQ`. Currently it leaks memory as the `malloc`ed memory isn't returned nor `free`d. That's a bug. In any case you can't check for "out of memory" like that. It makes no sense at all. Instead you need to check for NULL after **all** `malloc`s.

BTW: Use of global variables are in most cases a bad idea. In small "toy" programs you can do it but in bigger programs it will soon become very difficult to read, understand and maintain the code. Avoid global variables unless you have a very, very good reason.